# What font is used for the 'GRAPHIC DESIGN' logo on this website?

Tags: font-identification

What font is used for the 'GRAPHIC DESIGN' logo on this website?

Answer (score 1):

[Futura Demi](https://www.fonts.com/font/urw/futura/demi) & [Futura Medium](https://www.fonts.com/font/urw/futura/medium)

[image: Logo]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [Futura](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/futura/) Bold and Book.